# Tips for 100 Super Jump challenge to get Super Suit

Tags: super-mario-rpg

I want that damn leather jacket! Does anyone have any tips outside of 'the timing changes' or 'save state using an emulator' to complete [the 100 Super Jump quest](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_e1Z2V5ruSA)?

Comment: I forgot about that challenge ... I have some unfinished business to attend to >:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/snes/588739-super-mario-rpg-legend-of-the-seven-stars/faqs/5661) contains a series of tips for achieving 100 Super Jumps:

> - I recommend practicing your Jumps on
>     Spikey in Mushroom Way.  You should
>     not have the JUMP SHOES on when you do
>     this.  That way you can do the Jumps
>     repeatedly without causing damage (you
>     can have your other party members
>     block).  Or you could practice on the
>     Fink Flower in Bean Valley while
>     boosting your experience points.  A
>     "SCROOGE RING" will help cut down on
>     FP usage.
> - Can you imagine tolerating the classic
>     1-Up sounds that you hear when Mario
>     stomps the  enemy for about 95 jumps? 
>     That's why it's a good idea to hit the
>     mute button on you remote (or turn
>     down the volume).
> - Doing Super Jumps is such a repetitive
>     task.  It can get stressful at times. 
>     That's why it is important that you
>     remain relaxed while doing the jumps. 
>     The more frustrated you are, the more
>     likely you'll mess up.
> - The most important tip of all?  You
>     MUST have the proper mindset.  You
>     MUST prepare your mind.  Counting to
>     yourself all the way to 100 is very
>     likely to mess you up. What I
>     recommend you should do is divide the
>     number of jumps to 30 jump intervals. 
>     So you count to 30 then start over. 
>     That way, 100 just looks like 30, 30,
>     30, and 10.  If you happen to get used
>     to this line of thinking think 30, 30,
>     30, and 30 to improve your chances.

Essentially, practice before trying and concentrate properly during the task.

Comment: The timing for the jumps changes as number of jumps increases, though.  It's not as simple as being calm and doing the same thing 100 times.